# How to setup 'Scale to fit below built-in camera' for executable file?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

Apple offered [an option to hide the notch in new MacBook Pro](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212842) but there is no same option for executable files that I can run from the terminal. I need to run my app under [wine](https://www.winehq.org) that is a simple executable file.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there any solution to make it?